# Internet speed going 0bytes most frequently. I am using 20.04.02 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I think that after I upgraded to 20.04.02 LTS, my PC's internet connection doesn't work properly. I have checked my Wi-Fi and it is working pretty fine and smoothly on other devices. But in my Ubuntu PC sometimes it works pretty fast, as it should, but sometimes it takes a lot of time to open a webpage. It just shows the loading spinner on the top. I also have noticed that the internet speed is also good.

I have tried both with ethernet and Wi-Fi and it happens for both cases.

I have attached some of the screenshots and config of my PC

```sh
$ inxi -F
System:
  Host: manas Kernel: 5.8.0-55-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.7 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: B450M DS3H WIFI v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Gigabyte model: B450M DS3H WIFI-CF v: x.x 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: F50 
  date: 11/27/2019 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  Speed: 2196 MHz min/max: 2200/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2196 2: 2195 
  3: 2196 4: 2196 5: 2196 6: 2196 7: 2195 8: 2196 9: 2195 10: 2196 11: 2196 
  12: 2195 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] driver: nvidia v: 460.73.01 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.73.01 
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-55-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: r8169 
  IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 18:c0:4d:02:0b:47 
  Device-2: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] driver: iwlwifi 
  IF: wlp6s0 state: up mac: 34:7d:f6:52:b9:c1 
  IF-ID-1: br-20e2753e01ab state: down mac: 02:42:11:21:5c:d5 
  IF-ID-2: br-463913f2060c state: down mac: 02:42:d4:08:8d:7a 
  IF-ID-3: docker0 state: down mac: 02:42:fb:3c:bb:95 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.13 TiB used: 44.58 GiB (3.9%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-22MFCA0 
  size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Kingston model: SA400M8240G size: 223.57 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 218.57 GiB used: 44.58 GiB (20.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 50.5 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 45 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 34% 
Info:
  Processes: 440 Uptime: 1h 26m Memory: 15.64 GiB used: 4.30 GiB (27.5%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38 
manas@manas:~$
```

[image: speedtest screenshot]

Also I don't know what the three horizontal dots in this image are. They are not clickable. I don't know why they are shown sometimes.

[image: topbar three dots]

Comment: You may have perfectly fine wifi and ethernet connection to your router but the connection to your ISP is bumpy. A better way to check connection to outside world is to ping an outside server like `ping google.com`.

Comment: @Karlom ```sh manas@manas:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.77.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bom07s26-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.77.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=53.3 ms
64 bytes from bom07s26-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.77.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=51.7 ms
64 bytes from bom07s26-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.77.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=118 time=61.4 ms
64 bytes from bom07s26-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.77.46): icmp_seq=5 ttl=118 time=118 ms
64 bytes from bom07s26-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.77.46): icmp_seq=6 ttl=118 time=80.6 ms
```

Comment: @Karlom how do I fix it?

Comment: I am only getting this issue with this machine, even when I am using different wifi connection, it works in same way.

Comment: Didn't you have the speed issue before upgrading to `20.04`?

Comment: @Karlom No, I don't have any issue when I have been using 20.04